# Relate 2 fields ( input and select ) in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

There are 2 fields in my form, 1 text input and 1 select.
The main function is: When I type a number in input ( for ex: `123` ), it changes the select according to the value of the options in my select.

the problem is, when I type a number that doesn't exists in the select, the select input is set by this number, but I need that the select be set by "NULL" otherwise the validator doesn't work in this field.

Example: When you type: 001 - show bank 1, if 002 bank 2, if 003 bank 3, but if you type 005 for example, it shows nothing ( OK ), but the value of select is set 005, and I need that set NULL, because it being 005, in the validator there is a VALUE, but a "fake" value and the validator will pass with a fake value that doesn't exists in my object list in select.

PLUNKER: [plunker here](https://embed.plnkr.co/hu4FTNoJizKBuPHephhi/)

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!form3.controls['banco'].valid && form3.controls['banco'].touched}">
         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Banco:</label>
         <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>
           <input formControlName="codBanco" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Código Banco..."
           (keyup)="codBanco($event.target.value)">

           <select [(ngModel)]="form3.banco" formControlName="banco" class="form-control"
                 [class.invalid]="form3.controls['banco'].touched && !form3.controls['banco'].valid" (change)="bankChanged($event)">
                   <option *ngFor="let banks of bancos" [value]="banks.code">{{banks.title}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="form3.controls['banco'].hasError('required') && form3.controls['banco'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">Preencha o campo banco.</div>
         <div *ngIf="form3.controls['banco'].hasError('pattern') && form3.controls['banco'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">O campo banco aceita somente números.</div>

        </div>



   codBanco(tecla){
            this.form3.controls['banco'].patchValue(tecla);
            //if(this.form3.controls['banco'].value)
                console.log(this.bancos.code.indexOf(237));

        }

        bankChanged(evento){
            this.form3.controls['codBanco'].patchValue(evento.target.value);
        }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with plunker? And try not to use ngModel with reactive forms

Comment: Could you see the plunker please?

Comment: When you type: 001 - show bank 1, if 002 bank 2, if 003 bank 3, but if you type 005 for example, it shows nothing ( OK ), but the value of select is set 005, and I need that set NULL, because it would be wrong in validator

Comment: My native language isn't the english, I don't know if I got explaining